# Javascript Titanium, Looped label only show the last data out of the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, titanium

I've made a loop & used it in an var label. The idea was that it'll show every row out of the data array. Unfortunally it only shows the last row. Please help me out :/

This is my code:

```
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
item = data[i];



var togetherh = Titanium.UI.createLabel({

text : data[i].instelling_title,
font : {
    fontSize : 24,
    fontFamily : 'Helvetica Neue',
    fontWeight : 'bold'
},
color : 'black',
top : '10',
width : '100%',
textAlign : 'center',
height : 'auto',
left : 'auto',
touchEnabled : false

});

var together = Titanium.UI.createLabel({

text : data[i].instelling_id + '  ' + data[i].instelling_desc,
font : {
    fontSize : 12,
    fontFamily : 'Helvetica Neue'
},
color : 'black',
top : '50',
width : '85%',
textAlign : 'left',
height : 'auto',
left : 18,
touchEnabled : false

});
}
```

This is my Data Array:

```
var data = [
 {item: 'SCALDA 1', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {item: '14', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {item: '15', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '16', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '17', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '18', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '19', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: 'ROC22', instelling_title: 'ROC', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '21', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '22', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '13', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '12', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '3', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '4', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '5', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '6', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '799', instelling_title: 'ROC', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '8', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '9', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '10', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '11', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''},
 {instelling_id: '23', instelling_title: 'Scalda', instelling_desc: ''}
];
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

try like this :

```
var lblArr = [];

for(var i=0;i<5;i++){
    lblArr[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        text : i
    });
    Win.add(lblArr[i]);
}
```

You are creating `label` in the loop with same name, so all previous labels are getting overwritten and only the last label remains, thats why you are getting only the last label. By pushing labels in an array all labels are separated and you can get all labels.

Hope this will help you. :)

Comment: It's better if you explain ***why*** your code solves the problem. See [answer].

Comment: Doesnt work, tried it in a lot of different ways. Any suggestions :/?Thanks for the answer though ^^.

Comment: Thanks, do u also know why i can only place it in Ti.UI.currentWindow instead of my scrollView. Also all the lables are at the same location on my screen. Any more suggestions? :p
Thanks for the help with the loop btw. Works like a charm!

Comment: @user3493487 try to give `layout : 'vertical'` property to the `Win`or to your parentView on which you are adding the labels.